# How can i turn off the message received tick

Tags: sms, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I have a sony ericsoon xperia x10 mini.  when I send a text message, a tick appears to let tme know it has been received by the recipient.  This costs me money, how do I turn this off?  I have looked through the menu and cannot seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Message** App--> **Setting** -->***Turn off*  Delivery Report**

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to start the Messaging App to see if a Settings menu is attached to the application, rather than as a General Setting. Look for a setting similar to the name "Delivery Report" or "Delivery Confirmation", and turn it off.